# How do I get a resource pack on a single world on a server which has multiple worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-resource-packs

I run a Bukkit server where one of my main plugins is **Multiverse**(I also use Multiverse Portals). Now I have made a world with minigames, and I wanted the **Call of Duty plugin** to be one of my minigames. Later I discovered that I need to install a **resource pack** for the guns to *actually look* like guns. So I know how to install a resource pack on a normal server's world from the server properties, but if I use the resource pack on the server properties on the Bukkit server... it gets used on all the worlds. So I checked the worlds file from the Multiverse Core folder... but there was no resource pack option. So I just wanted to know if there was a way I can make the CoD resource pack activate on a single world and not work on the others. So is there a way? (I have seen it work on the Hypixel server so I want to know how they did it)
Thanks!

Comment: Multiverse doesn't have that option. You should look for an extra plugin to do this. There used to be one called MultiPack, but it got abandoned long ago.

Comment: You have to be thirteen or older to ask on this I thought, could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are looking for: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/world-resourcepacks.18950/

This allows you to change resource packs per-world as well as allowing you to use a command to switch packs.

Hypixel does it a bit differently though. The way they do it is they use a server wrapper called BungeeCord or something similar that basically connects players to different servers when they walk through portals. When you join a minigame on Hypixel, you have actually connected to a different server than you were on originally. This, however is more resource demanding in most circumstances as you are running many different servers at the same time.